# how to post an article by jquery using REST service of Drupal?

Tags: javascript

i want to create an article by rest services of drupal ?
as given in the documentation on [Drupal Post docs link](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/rest/3-post-for-creating-content-entities)

but it gives an error `Reference error : Drupal is not defined`

in the following line of code `jQuery.get(Drupal.url('rest/session/token'))`

here is my code based on docs

```
function getCsrfToken(callback) {
  jQuery.get(Drupal.url('rest/session/token'))
    .done(function (data) {
      var csrfToken = data;
      callback(csrfToken);
    });
}


function postNode(csrfToken, node) {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost/dr/entity/node?_format=hal_json',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/hal+json',
      'X-CSRF-Token': csrfToken

    },
    data: JSON.stringify(node),
    success: function (node) {
      console.log(node);
    }
  });
}

var newNode = {
  _links: {
    type: {
      href: 'http://localhost/dr/rest/type/node/article'
    }
  },
  type: {
    target_id: 'article'
  },
  title: {
    value: 'Example node title'
  }
}; 

getCsrfToken(function (csrfToken) {
  postNode(csrfToken, newNode);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enclose your javascript

```
(function ($, Drupal) {

  ...

})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

to access `Drupal` and the usual `$` for jQuery.

Comment: i didn't get this why to do this ? am i doing something wrong

Comment: see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/235705/why-and-what-wrapper-should-i-use-for-my-modules-javascript-file

Comment: and i am still getting `Reference error : Drupal is not defined` in  the line `  })(jQuery, Drupal) `

Comment: Did you declare a dependency for `core/drupal` in *.libraries.yml?

Comment: No , i just expose my api via rest ui module as shown in the Docs and try to post and article

Comment: OK, this javascript runs on a different site, not Drupal? Then you can't use `Drupal.url` and no relative path either. You have to provide an absolute path to the Drupal site `http://www.example.com/rest/session/token`